# Decoding JSON Error: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I am trying to parse some JSON data with SwiftUI/Combine and I am a bit confused on the error I am getting. I am really new to Combine, so I could be completely overlooking something. I'm sure this has nothing to do with the real issue, as this would probably happen if I was parsing the normal way with urlsession/@escaping.

Here is the code:

```
struct FilmModel: Identifiable, Codable {
let adult: Bool
let backdropPath: String
let budget: Int
let genres: [Genre]
let homepage: String
let id: Int
let imdbID, originalLanguage, originalTitle, overview: String
let popularity: Double
let posterPath: String
let productionCompanies: [ProductionCompany]
let productionCountries: [ProductionCountry]
let releaseDate: String
let revenue, runtime: Int
let spokenLanguages: [SpokenLanguage]
let status, tagline, title: String
let video: Bool
let voteAverage: Double
let voteCount: Int

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case adult
    case backdropPath = "backdrop_path"
    case budget
    case genres
    case homepage
    case id
    case imdbID = "imbd_id"
    case originalLanguage = "original_language"
    case originalTitle = "original_title"
    case overview
    case popularity
    case posterPath = "poster_path"
    case productionCompanies = "production_companies"
    case productionCountries = "production_countries"
    case releaseDate = "release_date"
    case revenue
    case runtime
    case spokenLanguages = "spoken_languages"
    case status, tagline, title
    case video
    case voteAverage = "vote_average"
    case voteCount = "vote_count"
}

struct Genre: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

struct ProductionCompany: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let logoPath: String?
    let name, originCountry: String
}

struct ProductionCountry: Codable {
    let iso3166_1, name: String
}

struct SpokenLanguage: Codable {
    let englishName, iso639_1, name: String
}
```

JSON response:

```
{
"adult": false,
"backdrop_path": "/rr7E0NoGKxvbkb89eR1GwfoYjpA.jpg",
"belongs_to_collection": null,
"budget": 63000000,
"genres": [
    {
        "id": 18,
        "name": "Drama"
    }
],
"homepage": "http://www.foxmovies.com/movies/fight-club",
"id": 550,
"imdb_id": "tt0137523",
"original_language": "en",
"original_title": "Fight Club",
"overview": "A ticking-time-bomb insomniac and a slippery soap salesman channel primal male aggression into a shocking new form of therapy. Their concept catches on, with underground \"fight clubs\" forming in every town, until an eccentric gets in the way and ignites an out-of-control spiral toward oblivion.",
"popularity": 46.456,
"poster_path": "/pB8BM7pdSp6B6Ih7QZ4DrQ3PmJK.jpg",
"production_companies": [
    {
        "id": 508,
        "logo_path": "/7PzJdsLGlR7oW4J0J5Xcd0pHGRg.png",
        "name": "Regency Enterprises",
        "origin_country": "US"
    },
    {
        "id": 711,
        "logo_path": "/tEiIH5QesdheJmDAqQwvtN60727.png",
        "name": "Fox 2000 Pictures",
        "origin_country": "US"
    },
    {
        "id": 20555,
        "logo_path": "/hD8yEGUBlHOcfHYbujp71vD8gZp.png",
        "name": "Taurus Film",
        "origin_country": "DE"
    },
    {
        "id": 54051,
        "logo_path": null,
        "name": "Atman Entertainment",
        "origin_country": ""
    },
    {
        "id": 54052,
        "logo_path": null,
        "name": "Knickerbocker Films",
        "origin_country": "US"
    },
    {
        "id": 25,
        "logo_path": "/qZCc1lty5FzX30aOCVRBLzaVmcp.png",
        "name": "20th Century Fox",
        "origin_country": "US"
    },
    {
        "id": 4700,
        "logo_path": "/A32wmjrs9Psf4zw0uaixF0GXfxq.png",
        "name": "The Linson Company",
        "origin_country": "US"
    }
],
"production_countries": [
    {
        "iso_3166_1": "DE",
        "name": "Germany"
    },
    {
        "iso_3166_1": "US",
        "name": "United States of America"
    }
],
"release_date": "1999-10-15",
"revenue": 100853753,
"runtime": 139,
"spoken_languages": [
    {
        "english_name": "English",
        "iso_639_1": "en",
        "name": "English"
    }
],
"status": "Released",
"tagline": "Mischief. Mayhem. Soap.",
"title": "Fight Club",
"video": false,
"vote_average": 8.4,
"vote_count": 22054
```

Data service:

```
class FilmDataService {
@Published var films: [FilmModel] = []

var filmSubscription: AnyCancellable?

init() {
    getFilms()
}

private func getFilms() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=<key>") else { return }
    
    filmSubscription = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default))
        .tryMap { (output) -> Data in
            guard let response = output.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                  response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300 else {
                throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
            }
            return output.data
        }
        .decode(type: [FilmModel].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink { (completion) in
            switch completion {
            case .finished:
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        } receiveValue: { [weak self] (returnedFilms) in
            self?.films = returnedFilms
            self?.filmSubscription?.cancel()
        }

}
```

View model:

```
class FilmViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var tabBarImageNames = ["house", "rectangle.stack", "clock.arrow.circlepath", "square.and.arrow.down"]
@Published var films: [FilmModel] = []

private let dataService = FilmDataService()
private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

init() {
    addSubscribers()
}

func addSubscribers() {
    dataService.$films
        .sink { [weak self] (returnedFilms) in
            self?.films = returnedFilms
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

Comment: The error is right, the JSON is clearly a dictionary, please note the enclosing `{}`. So it’s **one** film, `FilmModel.self`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Codable: Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55796157/codable-expected-to-decode-arrayany-but-found-a-dictionary-instead)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my observations. Your error is probably not to do with Combine.

you are trying to decode "[FilmModel].self", but the response is only for one film, FilmModel.self.

Also I would make most/all var in your FilmModel etc... optional, add "?".
It works well in my test.

EDIT:

This is the code I use to test my answer. Works well for me:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine


@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var movies = FilmViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 50) {
            Text("movie test")
            ForEach(movies.films, id: \.id) { movie in
                Text(movie.title ?? "no title").foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
    }
}


class FilmDataService {
    @Published var films: [FilmModel] = []
    
    var filmSubscription: AnyCancellable?
    
    init() {
        getFilms()
    }
    
    private func getFilms() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=1f632307cea6ce33f288f9a232b9803b") else { return }
        
        filmSubscription = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default))
            .tryMap { (output) -> Data in
                guard let response = output.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                      response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300 else {
                          throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
                      }
                return output.data
            }
            .decode(type: FilmModel.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())  // <--- here
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { (completion) in
                switch completion {
                case .finished:
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            } receiveValue: { [weak self] (returnedFilms) in
                self?.films.append(returnedFilms)  // <--- here
                self?.filmSubscription?.cancel()
            }
    }
    
}

class FilmViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tabBarImageNames = ["house", "rectangle.stack", "clock.arrow.circlepath", "square.and.arrow.down"]
    @Published var films: [FilmModel] = []
    
    private let dataService = FilmDataService()
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        addSubscribers()
    }
    
    func addSubscribers() {
        dataService.$films
            .sink { [weak self] (returnedFilms) in
                self?.films = returnedFilms
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
}

struct FilmModel: Identifiable, Codable {
    let adult: Bool?
    let backdropPath: String?
    let budget: Int?
    let genres: [Genre]?
    let homepage: String?
    let id: Int
    let imdbID, originalLanguage, originalTitle, overview: String?
    let popularity: Double?
    let posterPath: String?
    let productionCompanies: [ProductionCompany]?
    let productionCountries: [ProductionCountry]?
    let releaseDate: String?
    let revenue, runtime: Int?
    let spokenLanguages: [SpokenLanguage]?
    let status, tagline, title: String?
    let video: Bool?
    let voteAverage: Double?
    let voteCount: Int?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case adult
        case backdropPath = "backdrop_path"
        case budget
        case genres
        case homepage
        case id
        case imdbID = "imbd_id"
        case originalLanguage = "original_language"
        case originalTitle = "original_title"
        case overview
        case popularity
        case posterPath = "poster_path"
        case productionCompanies = "production_companies"
        case productionCountries = "production_countries"
        case releaseDate = "release_date"
        case revenue
        case runtime
        case spokenLanguages = "spoken_languages"
        case status, tagline, title
        case video
        case voteAverage = "vote_average"
        case voteCount = "vote_count"
    }
}

struct Genre: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String?
}

struct ProductionCompany: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let logoPath: String?
    let name, originCountry: String?
}

struct ProductionCountry: Codable {
    let iso3166_1, name: String?
}

struct SpokenLanguage: Codable {
    let englishName, iso639_1, name: String?
}
```

Comment: sorry @vadian, I did not see your comment, before I posted my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I should have caught those issues, especially making all my var(s) optional. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

First of all, never write your **api key** (or any other keys) online!

Second of all:

It seems the endpoint that you are calling is returning **a single `FilmModel`**. So you have to decode it to **a single one**:

Change this:

```
.decode(type: [FilmModel].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
```

to this:

```
.decode(type: FilmModel.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
```

And then change this:

```
.sink { [weak self] (returnedFilms) in
    self?.films = returnedFilms
}
```

to:

```
.sink { [weak self] (returnedFilm) in
    self?.films = [returnedFilm]
}
```

---

#### Handle both single and multi object result

Some times you don't know if the server will return a single or multiple objects (and you don't have control on the server to fix that).
You can implement a custom decoder to handle both single and multi object responses:

```
enum FilmsResult {
    case single(FilmModel)
    case array([FilmModel])
}

extension FilmsResult: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let singleFilm = try? container.decode(FilmModel.self) {
            self = .single(singleFilm)
        } else {
            try self = .array(container.decode([FilmModel].self))
        }
    }
}

extension FilmsResult {
    var values: [FilmModel] {
        switch self {
        case .single(let film): return [film]
        case .array(let films): return films
        }
    }
}
```

Than you can decode the result to:

```
.decode(type: FilmsResult.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
```

and use it like:

```
.sink { [weak self] filmsResult in
    self?.films = filmsResult.values
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I went with another answer but I really like your code for multi object results. And yes your absolutely right I should not have left my key in the code.

Comment: im kinda having a similar issue, and working with a movies api too... in the json when having the poster images, it is in a dictionary way, but when having none, it returns an empty array [] , so im having Xcode intermittently  having trouble to decode... , can't figure how to handle this specific case still, the part having trouble is parte of the main structs, how can I go further down and do some type of case