# SwiftUI - Cannot display nested array from JSON response - "has no member 'title"

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swiftui, nested

I am trying to display some data that is in a nested array in my json response. I cannot access the data by calling films.results.title ( as shown below). My model should be fine as I used quickType and this is something I've done before in a similar project.

Error: "Value of type '[Result]' has no member 'title'

I do not understand why [Result] has no member 'title'. As in my model 'title' is clearly nested inside of [Result] and [Result] is clearly nested inside of TRFilmModel. Any help on how to display the the data inside of the Result struct would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

JSON:

```
{
    "page":1,
    "results":[
        {
        "adult":false,
        "backdrop_path":"/gNBCvtYyGPbjPCT1k3MvJuNuXR6.jpg",
        "genre_ids":[35,18,10749],
        "id":19404,
        "original_language":"hi",
        "original_title":"दिलवाले दुल्हनिया ले जायेंगे",
        "overview":"Raj is a rich, carefree, happy-go-lucky second generation NRI. Simran is the daughter of Chaudhary Baldev Singh, who in spite of being an NRI is very strict about adherence to Indian values. Simran has left for India to be married to her childhood fiancé. Raj leaves for India with a mission at his hands, to claim his lady love under the noses of her whole family. Thus begins a saga.",
        "popularity":17.155,
        "poster_path":"/2CAL2433ZeIihfX1Hb2139CX0pW.jpg",
        "release_date":"1995-10-20",
        "title":"Dilwale Dulhania Le Jayenge",
        "video":false,
        "vote_average":8.7,
        "vote_count":3047
        
        },
        {
        "adult":false,
        "backdrop_path":"/iNh3BivHyg5sQRPP1KOkzguEX0H.jpg",
        "genre_ids":[18,80],
        "id":278,
        "original_language":"en",
        "original_title":"The Shawshank Redemption",
        "overview":"Framed in the 1940s for the double murder of his wife and her lover, upstanding banker Andy Dufresne begins a new life at the Shawshank prison, where he puts his accounting skills to work for an amoral warden. During his long stretch in prison, Dufresne comes to be admired by the other inmates -- including an older prisoner named Red -- for his integrity and unquenchable sense of hope.",
        "popularity":51.507,
        "poster_path":"/q6y0Go1tsGEsmtFryDOJo3dEmqu.jpg",
        "release_date":"1994-09-23",
        "title":"The Shawshank Redemption",
        "video":false,
        "vote_average":8.7,
        "vote_count":19292
        },
        {
        "adult":false,
        "backdrop_path":"/rSPw7tgCH9c6NqICZef4kZjFOQ5.jpg",
        "genre_ids":[18,80],
        "id":238,
        "original_language":"en",
        "original_title":"The Godfather",
        "overview":"Spanning the years 1945 to 1955, a chronicle of the fictional Italian-American Corleone crime family. When organized crime family patriarch, Vito Corleone barely survives an attempt on his life, his youngest son, Michael steps in to take care of the would-be killers, launching a campaign of bloody revenge.",
        "popularity":48.481,
        "poster_path":"/3bhkrj58Vtu7enYsRolD1fZdja1.jpg",
        "release_date":"1972-03-14",
        "title":"The Godfather",
        "video":false,
        "vote_average":8.7,
        "vote_count":14551
        },
    ],
    "total_pages":447,
    "total_results":8926
}
```

Model:

```
struct TRFilmModel: Codable {
    let page: Int?
    let results: [Result]
    let totalPages, totalResults: Int?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case page, results
        case totalPages = "total_pages"
        case totalResults = "total_results"
    }
}

struct Result: Identifiable, Codable {
    let adult: Bool?
    let backdropPath: String?
    let genreIDS: [Int]?
    let id: Int
    let originalTitle: String
    let originalLanguage, overview: String?
    let popularity: Double?
    let posterPath, releaseDate: String?
    let title: String
    let video: Bool?
    let voteAverage: Double?
    let voteCount: Int?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case adult, id, overview, popularity, title, video
        case backdropPath = "backdrop_path"
        case genreIDS = "genre_ids"
        case originalTitle = "original_title"
        case originalLanguage = "original_language"
        case posterPath = "poster_path"
        case releaseDate = "release_date"
        case voteAverage = "vote_average"
        case voteCount = "vote_count"
    }
}
```

Data service:

```
class FilmDataService {
    @Published var films: [TRFilmModel] = []
    
    var filmSubscription: AnyCancellable?
    
    private let apiKey = "?api_key=<locked>"
    private let baseAPIURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3"
    
    init() {
        getFilms()
    }
    
    private func getFilms() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "\(baseAPIURL)/movie/top_rated\(apiKey)") else { return }
        
        filmSubscription = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default))
            .tryMap { (output) -> Data in
                guard let response = output.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                      response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300 else {
                    throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
                }
                return output.data
            }
            .decode(type: [TRFilmModel].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { (completion) in
                switch completion {
                case .finished:
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            } receiveValue: { [weak self] (returnedFilms) in
                self?.films = returnedFilms
                self?.filmSubscription?.cancel()
            }

    }
}
```

View Model:

```
class FilmViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tabBarImageNames = ["house", "rectangle.stack", "clock.arrow.circlepath", "square.and.arrow.down"]
    @Published var films: [TRFilmModel] = []
    
    private let dataService = FilmDataService()
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        addSubscribers()
    }
    
    func addSubscribers() {
        dataService.$films
            .sink { [weak self] (returnedFilms) in
                self?.films = returnedFilms
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

View:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var fvm: FilmViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                 ForEach(fvm.films) { films in
                    Text(films.results.title)     <------- Error
                  }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you already asked the same type of question here:
 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68507900/decoding-json-error-expected-to-decode-arrayany-but-found-a-dictionary-inste
 
 is there something you cannot understand in the answer?  You are trying to decode "[TRFilmModel].self", but the response is only for one film, TRFilmModel.self.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is absolutely correct. Your `results` constant, which is an array of result, does not have a member called `title`. It has elements which are of type `Result` which do have a member called `title`. You need to call `.title` on a single element of the array, not on the array itself.

```
List {
     ForEach(fvm.films) { films in
          ForEach(films, id: \.self) { result in
               Text(result.title) 
      }
}
```

Now, while that will show you a list of film titles, I don't think it will come out as you want because you will cycle through each `film` in your view model, and then cycle through each result in the film, which appears to have multiple films. You may want to rethink your view model as something seems off there. You didn't include a sample of the JSON, so it is tough to know what that issue is. However, that is a different question, so if you need help on that one, ask a new question.

Edit:

The issue isn't the `ForEach` in the `List` the issue is your view model. The JSON, as I suspected, is simply an array of films. You have set your view model up to be an array of that array of films. The only way that would make sense is if the JSON had the data grouped by something like Genre, but is doesn't; it is simply a flat array.

The issue is in your `FilmDataService` class. You define the `@Published var films` as an array of your view model. The view model already contains your array of films. Simply change that to:

```
class FilmDataService {

    @Published var films: [Result] = []
```

In your `getFilms()` you then need to return an array of `Result`, not an array of `TRFilmModel`.

Comment: I edited the original question to include the json, I understand what you mean that "Your results constant, which is an array of result, does not have a member called title. It has elements..." But I feel like there should be a better way to display and access that data. Maybe not, but I appreciate your response, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

here is again the same type of answer I gave you before, that works:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MovieView()
        }
    }
}

struct TRFilmModel: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()  // <--- here
    let page: Int?
    let results: [Result]
    let totalPages, totalResults: Int?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case page, results
        case totalPages = "total_pages"
        case totalResults = "total_results"
    }
}

struct Result: Identifiable, Codable {
    let adult: Bool?
    let backdropPath: String?
    let genreIDS: [Int]?
    let id: Int
    let originalTitle: String
    let originalLanguage, overview: String?
    let popularity: Double?
    let posterPath, releaseDate: String?
    let title: String
    let video: Bool?
    let voteAverage: Double?
    let voteCount: Int?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case adult, id, overview, popularity, title, video
        case backdropPath = "backdrop_path"
        case genreIDS = "genre_ids"
        case originalTitle = "original_title"
        case originalLanguage = "original_language"
        case posterPath = "poster_path"
        case releaseDate = "release_date"
        case voteAverage = "vote_average"
        case voteCount = "vote_count"
    }
}

struct MovieView: View {
    @StateObject var fvm = FilmViewModel()  // <--- for testing
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                if let firstMovie = fvm.films.first {  // <--- here for testing
                    ForEach(firstMovie.results, id: \.id) { movie in
                        Text(movie.title).foregroundColor(.red)
                    }
                }
            }

// or do this
//            List {
//                ForEach(fvm.films, id: \.id) { films in
//                    ForEach(films.results, id: \.id) { movie in
//                        Text(movie.title).foregroundColor(.red)
//                    }
//                }
//            }

        }
    }
}

class FilmDataService {
    @Published var films: [TRFilmModel] = []
    
    var filmSubscription: AnyCancellable?
    
    init() {
        getFilms()
    }
    
    private func getFilms() {
        let apiKey = "?api_key=<locked>"  // <--- put your key here
        let baseAPIURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "\(baseAPIURL)/movie/top_rated\(apiKey)") else { return }
        
        filmSubscription = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default))
            .tryMap { (output) -> Data in
                guard let response = output.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                      response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300 else {
                          throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
                      }
                return output.data
            }
            .decode(type: TRFilmModel.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())  // <--- here
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { (completion) in
                switch completion {
                case .finished:
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            } receiveValue: { [weak self] (returnedFilms) in
                self?.films.append(returnedFilms)  // <--- here
                self?.filmSubscription?.cancel()
            }
    }
    
}

class FilmViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tabBarImageNames = ["house", "rectangle.stack", "clock.arrow.circlepath", "square.and.arrow.down"]
    @Published var films: [TRFilmModel] = []
    
    private let dataService = FilmDataService()
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        addSubscribers()
    }
    
    func addSubscribers() {
        dataService.$films
            .sink { [weak self] (returnedFilms) in
                self?.films = returnedFilms
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
}
```